# Need help finding way to Automatically add product attribute based off of tag

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to find either some code or a plugin that is able to find a product tag and based off of what the tag is, make a new or assign an existing attribute to that product.

i have tried searching for a solution but cannot find one.

eg1: Product has tag:
brand_example

i want that to turn into the value example under the attribute brand automatically

eg2: Product has tag:
mat_example

would turn into the value example under the attribute material.

Comment: Go ahead and add some code you have already tried.

Comment: Hey Joey. I havent been able to find anything that seems like it would work for this issue. I have found similar issues but the one thing that is different is that i need it to look at the tag brand_example and extract just whats after the underscore, and turn that into the value for that products attribute of brand. And it does that automatically for ever product that it finds a tag that contains brand.